# Error in rendering OSM Maps

Tags: openstreetmap

I am working on creating a OSM Server and want to display the correct map of India with disputed boundaries. I have followed the following link: http://xsce.org/wiki/generating_map_tiles#disputed_borders to correct India map using geojson file. But I am getting below error messages in my rendering logs. Can anyone help in resolving this issue?

```
renderd[23400]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': OGR Plugin: cannot find layer by name 'OGRGeoJSON' in dataset '/usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/geojson/boundary_claimed_by_india/map.geojson'  encountered during parsing of layer 'india_boundary' in Layer at line 1041 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'

renderd[23400]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': OGR Plugin: cannot find layer by name 'OGRGeoJSON' in dataset '/usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/geojson/boundary_claimed_by_india/map.geojson'  encountered during parsing of layer 'india_boundary' in Layer at line 1041 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'

renderd[23400]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': OGR Plugin: cannot find layer by name 'OGRGeoJSON' in dataset '/usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/geojson/boundary_claimed_by_india/map.geojson'  encountered during parsing of layer 'india_boundary' in Layer at line 1041 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'

renderd[23400]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': OGR Plugin: cannot find layer by name 'OGRGeoJSON' in dataset '/usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/geojson/boundary_claimed_by_india/map.geojson'  encountered during parsing of layer 'india_boundary' in Layer at line 1041 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong layer specifications in my OSMBright.xml file.

I ran the following command to know the exact layer available in geojson file.

osm@osm:/usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/geojson/boundary_claimed_by_india$ ogrinfo india-soi.geojson
INFO: Open of `india-soi.geojson'
      using driver`GeoJSON' successful.

1: india-soi (Multi Polygon)

In my case the layer name was india-soi

I changed the OSMBright.xml style file and it worked fine for me

**Wrong code :**

```
> <Datasource>
>        <Parameter name="layer"><![CDATA[OGRGeoJSON]]></Parameter>
>        <Parameter name="type"><![CDATA[ogr]]></Parameter>
>        <Parameter name="file"><![CDATA[/home/osm/geojson/india-osm.geojson]]></Parameter>
> </Datasource>
```

**Right code**

```
> <Datasource>
>        <Parameter name="layer"><![CDATA[india-soi]]></Parameter>
>        <Parameter name="type"><![CDATA[ogr]]></Parameter>
>        <Parameter name="file"><![CDATA[/home/osm/geojson/india-osm.geojson]]></Parameter>
> </Datasource>
```